# How to simultate 3 monitors on a system that only has 2 monitors?

Tags: windows-7, display, multiple-monitors

I need to emulate extra monitors. For example if my system is dual-monitor, I need to trick Windows to think I have 3 monitors or more (and somehow switch between those virtual monitors to see the image).

**IMPORTANT!**

- Windows must think I have 3 monitors (the monitors must appear in 'Screen Resolution' panel so I can change their 'physical' layout.
- No hardware products please.

It doesn't have to be perfect/efficient. I need this only temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simulate monitors by installing an INF file. 
[EDID](http://www.overclock.net/t/721136/how-to-use-an-inf-to-override-the-monitor-edid)

Answer (score 1):

[VirtuaWin](http://virtuawin.sourceforge.net/) seems to be a leading contender for multiple virtual desktops.

From the site:
VirtuaWin is a virtual desktop manager for the Windows operating system (Win9x/ME/NT/Win2K/XP/Win2003/Vista/Win7). A virtual desktop manager lets you organize applications over several [virtual desktops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_desktop) (also called ‘workspaces’). Virtual desktops are very common in Unix/Linux, and once you get accustomed to using them, they become an essential part of a productive workflow.

Just tried it - I don't know if this would be good/bad for you, but each desktop is the same number of screens (e.g. A 4 desktop setting, with a 2 screen system, results in a virtual desktop that is 8 screens)

Comment: Thanks. The software you point to is cool but it is not what I need. Sorry, I wasn't aware it cam be done this way. I updated my question to rule-out this kind of 'solutions'. +1 anyway for a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to simply connect multiple cables to one monitor, if you have spare cables laying around (and extra outputs/inputs).

Comment: 'if you have spare cables' - spare cables are not the problem. The video outputs supported by a laptop (for example) is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I may not have understood the question completely, but I know is you have a USB to video adapter, that can work.
Also installing the software only can also help.

For example: I have used USB HP DOcking station that has VDO support. with that installed, there is a 3rd monitor shown in the display screen even though I have 2 ports (one through VGA on laptop - one through DP port and the third goes through USB Dock)

if you are not looking for any additional hardware or new software solutions, just what Windows has, then that may not be possible.

Also what Video card/driver are you using on your system. someone Might have something for that.

Comment: Sorry, not my solution. What is I need to simulate 10 monitors? I need to buy 10 adapters and 10 monitors.

Comment: Just curious what video card is on the laptop? ATI/AMD ..? I think I saw some cards have some capability (I have seen them but never used them) that can allow multiple monitors using DP. maybe that can help.